# Azure web App service Not working (slow response) when I reload it or Open in new tab,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web, caching, azure-web-app-service

Suddenly my Azure App service(website) stop working(slow response from server side), When I try to open it in new tab or Reload it & only works when I freshly reload it & cache cleared.

App service working fine outside of India , Arr affinity also disabled. not able to figure out where is issue ? at code level or server or Azure platform

Answer (score 0):

This error related to application and you can check error why these happening. using Application Insights and Azure App Service diagnostics.

You can check actual error using Application Insights.

1. Go to application Insights -> Click on failed request.
   [image]
2. Click on Exception types.
   [image]

And check by Diagnose and solve problems . Investigate how your app is performing, diagnose issues, and discover how to improve your application.

1. Go to App Service -> Diagnose and solve problems.
   [image]

And other issue related to this problem.

- Network issue, not response for request
- db queries taking long time to response.
- Application not handling error properly
  This error is related to the application and you can check error why these happening. using Application Insights and Azure App Service diagnostics.

You can check actual errors using Application Insights.

1. Go to application Insights -> Click on failed request.
   [image]
2. Click on Exception types.
   [image]

And check by diagnosing and solving problems. Investigate how your app is performing, diagnose issues, and discover how to improve your application.

1. Go to App Service -> Diagnose and solve problems.
   [image]

And other issues related to this problem.

- DB queries take a long time to respond.
- Application not handling error properly
- Network issue, not response for the request

Comment: Thanks @PunitSharma I could see error in signalR issues in my application.

Comment: @AkshayMane, you can check issues by using same steps.